# APK is installing on device but doesn't start automatically

Tags: android

I am working on an android application with android studio, I needed to use a library that use other libraries built in.So I have added the next dependencies to my project.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'net.koofr:java-koofr:1.2.8'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
    compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.1.2'
}
```

I am trying to connect to a cloud system using a username and a password using koofr library. One of my problem that I had when I started the project was that I didn't know that koofr uses another dependencies to work. I have added the rest of dependenceies.

My build.gradle from app folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'net.koofr:java-koofr:1.2.8'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
    compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.1.2'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "marianpavel.digimusicstream"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.ClientHelper'
    }
}

repositories{
    maven {
        url 'http://maven.restlet.com'
    }
}
```

You can note that dependencies are in the top of my build graddle.

The next problem I had is to get errors when I was trying to run the application, error like:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE
    File 1: C:\Users\marinica\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.8\e04e8b2defcbf2e365b75498a36475f2cddc44ba\jackson-core-asl-1.9.8.jar
    File 2: C:\Users\marinica\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.8\e04e8b2defcbf2e365b75498a36475f2cddc44ba\jackson-core-asl-1.9.8.jar
```

so I have modified the gradle file adding all these excludes:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.ClientHelper'
}
```

Also I noticed in gradle console some warnings that I have tryed to solve but I didn't find any solution, some conflicts with my dependencies with build in libraries from android studio/android.

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.95 secs
```

I am saying all of these problems that I have encounter because now when I try to run my application with the login screen I can install on device but it doesn't show up automatically, I find in app manager that is installed but I don't see it anywhere where I can be able to run it. This is strange and it never happened to me before. If any more informations are needed I can provide them.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="marianpavel.digimusicstream" >

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginForm"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_form" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you.

Comment: post your manifest file also

Comment: I have added the manifest to the post too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide the launcher entry in your manifest. Add the launcher `intent-filter` to your activity to fix the problem.

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, still doesn't open the application in Device.

Comment: My bad it did work, I missed a closing bracket and now it's working, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace your your manifest code with below one.

```
<activity
            android:name="marianpavel.digimusicstream.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

For automatic launch activity  make it launcher activity